# is there is any way to get all keys from localizable string file?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, nslocalizedstring

So basically I want to get keys structure from the localizable file because when we have too much string in the local file then it's very pathetic to open a file and search for specific string each time.

ex:

```
let localizeStr = NSLocalizedString(Local.keyName, comment: "")
```

keyName = any key in localizable.strings file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to read the file and parse it's content line by line and store it's keys in an **NSArray** , then you ready to do what you want ...

Comment: In NSArray you need to remember index of the key. I want a solution like an enum pair with the .dot syntax all keys will be visible. I am working on that :)

Comment: Then parse the line as key,value and store it in NSDictionary